# Shell script printing out "read: missing arguments"

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that I want to run two instances of my executable "server" in the background. However, when I run the script I get the error "read: missing arguments". This problem does not occur when I remove the "&" to run in the background, but then it produces an undesirable behavior.

The server executable is followed by pairs of addresses and ports, but I removed any code checking for correct number of arguments. Where is the error being thrown, and how can I get this script to work?

```
#Location of executable.
SERVER=server
SERVER_NAME=`echo $SERVER | sed 's#.*/\(.*\)#\1#g'`

$SERVER localhost 4111 localhost 4222 &
$SERVER localhost 4222 localhost 4111 &

echo "Press ENTER to quit"
read
pkill $SERVER_NAME
```

Comment: There's no need to use pkill.  If your system supports it, just use `kill 0` to kill all members of the process group.  Otherwise, do `$SERVER ... & p1=$!; $SERVER ... & p2=$!; ... kill $p1 $p2;`  (that is, keep track of your children so you can kill them cleanly.)

Comment: This script was given to us by our professor to test our code for server. pkill seems to be working fine, but the question I have is why can I run the server exactly the same way (with & at the end), but when it's in the script, it won't work and tell me I'm missing arguments?

Comment: try @sampson-chen 's change. I bet it will work. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` expects a variable after it to read into:

```
read var1
```

If you are only using `read` to block the execution of the script until you receive some response from the user, just use the above suggestion.

---

Also, this probably isn't what you intend to do:

```
SERVER=server
SERVER_NAME=`echo $SERVER | sed 's#.*/\(.*\)#\1#g'`
```

because after that executes, `SERVER_NAME` would just be the string `server`

If `server` is a command on your environment, what you probably meant to do is:

```
SERVER_NAME=$(server | sed 's#.*/\(.*\)#\1#g'`)
```

Comment: This is actually a script given by a professor to test out code, but I'm mainly wondering why I can execute it manually with the "&" at the front but not while its in this script. SERVER_NAME was there I assume if we were running the script in a different directory.

Comment: And I tried your change with SERVER_NAME, but it told me unexpected usage of SERVER_NAME=$.

Comment: Oops sorry for triple comment, but the `read var1` thing did it. Thanks!

Comment: @theeggman85: the comment about `SERVER_NAME` only applies with the assumption that `server` is actually a valid command on your environment =)

Comment: No, `read` doesn't expect a variable! from `help read`: "If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable."

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I was curious about that part too; maybe his shell's `read` is different? It was the only way I could think of to explain `"read: missing arguments"`.